# Set number format in Fields Table

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to set a number format e.g. percentage, currency, etc. of a numeric field to display in Identify Results panel?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to directly set a number format for display in the Identify Results panel. Here's a workaround.

Use the field calculator to add a new field. Check the box for **virtual field** and set the data type to **string**. Use a formula to copy the values from the field you are interested in and format or append it with a symbol. E.g. for currency, you could use the expression

> '£' || "fieldName"

For percentage, use

> "fieldName" * 100 || '%'

The new virtual field will auto-update when the source field is updated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry should have posted this here... Yes, that worked. Thank You... finding out how to add a virtual field was a bit tricky, for newbies, it is called Field Calculator and is the little abacus looking widget at the top of the Fields Dialog box. Great tip Thanks Again! The expression I used was

`concat('$ ', format_number( "fieldName",2))` 
for currency and 
`>concat('% ', format_number( "fieldName",1))` 
for percentage.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I added a screenshot to make it more clear for anyone else with the same question.